# Create function to update specific values of nested php array

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function with four parameters, two of them optional, to replace default values in the $image array. However, the second part of the function that deals with the portrait and landscape values doesn't work as intended. Specifying either portrait or landscape parameters completely replaces the original 'ratio' key values, leaving only one of them. The array_replace rather than replacing a specific element,  replaces the whole 'ratio' subarray.

Snippet of default multi-dimensional $image array:

```
$image = [
    'name' => 'placeholder',
    'caption' => 'placeholder',
    'ratio' => ['portrait' => '3x4', 'landscape' => '3x2'],
];
```

Function to push customizable values into the original $image array to use in template pages to generate custom srcset image html:

```
function imageArray($name, $caption, $portrait = NULL, $landscape = NULL)
{
    global $image;
    $new = array("name" => $name, "caption" => $caption);
    if ($portrait) {
        $portrait = array('ratio' => ["portrait" => $portrait]);
    }
    if ($landscape) {
        $landscape = array('ratio' => ["landscape" => $landscape]);
    }
    $image = (array_replace($image, $new, $portrait, $landscape));
}
```

As it is now,

```
function prettyArray($a)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($a);
    echo "</pre>";
}

imageArray('sam', "Me in the park", "9x3", "3x5");
prettyArray($image);
```

Produces

Array

```
(
    [name] => sam
    [caption] => Me in the park
    [ratio] => Array
        (
            [landscape] => 3x5
        )

)
```

I want it to produce:

```
Array
(
    [name] => sam
    [caption] => Me in the park
    [ratio] => Array
        (
            [portrait] => 9x3
            [landscape] => 3x5
        )

)
```

As stated below in my follow up post, the function needs to handle the following three scenarios, outputting the default $image array values (defined at top) for 'portrait' and 'landscape' when they are not passed in the function. Both ratio elements values should output, whether they are default or modified:

Example of potential cases:

```
// Case 1: $portrait and $landscape not defined.
imageArray('sam1', "Me in the park");
prettyArray($image);

// Case 2: only $portrait, not $landscape, defined.
imageArray('sam2', "Me in the park", "2x4");
prettyArray($image);

// Case 3: $landscape, not $portrait, defined.
imageArray('sam3', "Me in the park", [], "5x2");
prettyArray($image);

Desired outcome:

Array
(
    [name] => sam1
    [caption] => Me in the park
    [ratio] => Array
        (
            [portrait] => 3x4
            [landscape] => 3x2
        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => sam2
    [caption] => Me in the park
    [ratio] => Array
        (
            [portrait] => 2x4
            [landscape] => 3x2
        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => sam3
    [caption] => Me in the park
    [ratio] => Array
        (
            [portrait] => 2x4
            [landscape] => 5x2
        )

)
```

Comment: Defaulting `$portrait` and `$landscape` to `NULL` is not a good idea. https://3v4l.org/YOaBS  Better to make it an empty array by default if you going to unconditionally feed the variables to `array_replace()`.  What is your preferred output when one of those values is null (or empty) coming in?  Should the `ratio` element always contain the two elements? Or might the `ratio` element not be declared at all if there are no values to declare inside of it?

Comment: Rather than answering.  Please [edit] your question so that these fringe cases are clear.  Then maybe I can provide a better answer.

Comment: We don't know what `$image` is.

Comment: Not sure why my question was closed? The two links given in the official closed statement are similar but not the same. My question asked about how to write a standalone function to update an array, none of the answers given in those links do that. (As a beginner in php, I wouldn't have been able to generalize them to my situation.) Nor do they answer how to use array_replace or array_replace_recursive. .

Comment: The pages nominated in the page closure do not need to match your question identically.  If matching snowflake-to-snowflake was required, then we wouldn't have duplicates -- all questions are slightly different.  No.  The nominated pages merely need to give the necessary insights to resolve the question.  I believe the advice within these pages is sufficient to resolve your simple task of assigning values to a new array structure.  The truth is that no function calls are necessary since you expressed that you are happy to have null values as subarray values.

Comment: I wouldn't of come up with the solution, as posted below, looking at those linked questions. Perhaps, I wasn't clear enough in my original question  I don't want to output null values. I want either to output default array values or those passed through a function. The image array example is only an excerpt of a much larger array used to generate custom srcset responsive html in my web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `array_replace` is replacing the `ratio` key.
You may use `array_replace_recursive` instead:

```php
function imageArray($name, $caption, $portrait = NULL, $landscape = NULL)
{
    global $image;
    $new = array("name" => $name, "caption" => $caption);
    if ($portrait) {
        $portrait = array('ratio' => ["portrait" => $portrait]);
    }
    if ($landscape) {
        $landscape = array('ratio' => ["landscape" => $landscape]);
    }
    $image = array_replace_recursive($image, $new, $portrait, $landscape);
}
```

But you may also do this:

```php
function imageArray($name, $caption, $portrait = NULL, $landscape = NULL)
{
    global $image;
    $new = [
        'name' => $name,
        'caption' => $caption,
    ];
    if ($portrait) {
        $new['ratio']['portrait'] = $portrait;
    }
    if ($landscape) {
        $new['ratio']['landscape'] = $landscape;
    }
}
```

You can also get rid of the `global` (usually, using it is a bad practice) like this:

```php
<?php
function imageArray($name, $caption, $portrait = NULL, $landscape = NULL)
{
    $image = [
        'name' => $name,
        'caption' => $caption,
    ];
    if ($portrait) {
        $image['ratio']['portrait'] = $portrait;
    }
    if ($landscape) {
        $image['ratio']['landscape'] = $landscape;
    }
    return $image;
}

$image = imageArray('sam', 'Me in the park', '9x3', '3x5');
```

Or like this:

```php
function imageArray($name, $caption, $portrait = NULL, $landscape = NULL)
{
    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'caption' => $caption,
        'ratio' => [
            'portrait' => $portrait,
            'landscape' => $landscape,
        ]
    ];
}
```

## Edited

If you want to fall to default values:

```php
function imageArray($name, $caption, $portrait = NULL, $landscape = NULL)
{
    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'caption' => $caption,
        'ratio' => [
            'portrait' => $portrait ?? '3x4',
            'landscape' => $landscape ?? '3x2',
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: And here is [another way with `array_replace_recursive()`](https://3v4l.org/WCkAB) but the question details are foggy about what the result should be if `$portrait` and/or `$landscape` are falsey.

Comment: @mickmackusa. Whatever is not declared as $portrait and/or $landscape when running the function should default to original Array values. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Sam then you want Pedro's final script.  Otherwise, you are still not clear.

Comment: @mickmackusa, The default array values is stated in the original post as $image = ['name' => 'placeholder', 'caption' => 'placeholder', 'ratio' => ['portrait' => '3x4', 'landscape' => '3x2']]; If values for either portrait and/or landscape is not passed with the function, the default array values should remain. Yes, Pedro's first and second examples is what I accepted as my answer (see my follow up post).

Answer (score 0):

Pedro's first two examples produces what I want (both still uses $image as global), but here I am using empty array brackets instead of NULL for the first approach, for fallback to make the parameters truly optional.

```
// Set default Array
$image = [
    'name' => 'placeholder',
    'caption' => 'placeholder',
    'ratio' => ['portrait' => '3x4', 'landscape' => '3x2'],
];

// Define Function to modify Array
function imageArray($name, $caption, $portrait = [], $landscape = [])
{
    global $image;
    $new = array("name" => $name, "caption" => $caption);
    if ($portrait) {
        $portrait = array('ratio' => ["portrait" => $portrait]);
    }
    if ($landscape) {
        $landscape = array('ratio' => ["landscape" => $landscape]);
    }
    $image = array_replace_recursive($image, $new, $portrait, $landscape);
}

// Alternative function
function imageArray($name, $caption, $portrait = NULL, $landscape = NULL)
{
    global $image;
    $new = [
        'name' => $name,
        'caption' => $caption,
    ];
    if ($portrait) {
        $new['ratio']['portrait'] = $portrait;
    }
    if ($landscape) {
        $new['ratio']['landscape'] = $landscape;
    }
    $image = array_replace_recursive($image, $new);
}

// Print out function modified Array to test:

function prettyArray($a)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($a);
    echo "</pre>";
}
// Case 1: $portrait and $landscape not defined.
imageArray('sam1', "Me in the park");
prettyArray($image);

// Case 2: only $portrait, not $landscape, defined.
imageArray('sam2', "Me in the park", "2x4");
prettyArray($image);

// Case 3: $landscape, not $portrait, defined. 
imageArray('sam3', "Me in the park", [], "5x2");
prettyArray($image);
```

Outputs all cases properly, with updated values;

```
Array
(
    [name] => sam1
    [caption] => Me in the park
    [ratio] => Array
        (
            [portrait] => 3x4
            [landscape] => 3x2
        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => sam2
    [caption] => Me in the park
    [ratio] => Array
        (
            [portrait] => 2x4
            [landscape] => 3x2
        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => sam3
    [caption] => Me in the park
    [ratio] => Array
        (
            [portrait] => 2x4
            [landscape] => 5x2
        )

)
```